# Get the SQL that was executed by a strongly typed dataset (C#)

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a lot of legacy C# code that unfortunately uses Strongly Typed Datasets.  My question is how do I get the Select Statement that was actually executed when the Strongly Typed Dataset is filled?

Comment: If you just need it for troubleshooting, then Sql Profiler can capture any statements executed against the target server/db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using typed dataset then all your procedures are mapped to proper methods in dataset (you can check the same in designer.cs).

You can select any of the method/procedure and go to properties and check the select command.

> how do I get the Select Statement that was actually executed when the
>   Strongly Typed Dataset is filled?

I believe you are using `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the typed dataset. In that case, you can just use `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand` property like

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will see the SQL statements in the TableAdapter in the Dataset Designer; right-click and select 'Configure'. However, there typically will be several queries in there - you will have to examine the source code to determine which one is called and with what parameters.